# Access Violation Error while doing marshal.copy from Intptr to Double[]

Tags: c#, pinvoke

This is not actual code. But I wanted to do similar things in my actual code. i.e Will get double pointer from C# and will fill vaules in to cpp code and will do marshal.copy into C# code from IntPtr to double []. This is what I tried. But it gives access violation.

C++ Code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void FillDoubleValues(IN UInt64 _NumSamplesToCapture, OUT double* pSamples)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _NumSamplesToCapture; i++)
    {
        pSamples[i] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("LibOperation.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static public extern voi FillDoubleValues( [IN] UInt64 _NumSamplesToCapture, out IntPtr pSamples);
   

void main(){

UInt64 NumSamplesToCapture = 5000;

Intptr Sample;

FillDoubleValues(NumSamplesToCapture, out Sample);

double[] ys1 = new double[NumSamplesToCapture];

Marshal.Copy(Samples, ys1, 0, ys1.Length);

// ys1 wil be used to plot values

}
```

Marshal.Copy gives an error **"System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

Any mistake I'm making here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular array marshalling, you don't need to marshal it yourself

```cs
[DllImport("LibOperation.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static public extern void FillDoubleValues(
  UInt64 _NumSamplesToCapture,
  [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] out double[] pSamples
);
   

void main()
{
    UInt64 NumSamplesToCapture = 5000;
    double[] ys1;
    FillDoubleValues(NumSamplesToCapture, out ys1);
}
```

Comment: It gives System.ExecutionEngineException if we do like above On calling func FillDoubleValues

Comment: I've added `MarshalAs` now, hopefully that should work

Comment: @Charlieface What if you are unsure about the size of the array to create? I.E. here `NumSamplesToCapture` is set in c#, but what if this varies and will change. Is the way to allocate more memory than needed, then reduce? Or is there a way to change this memory allocation in c++.

Comment: `NumSamplesToCapture` is a variable, you can get it from anywhere. You can pass it to C++ as a `ref` variable, so that C++ can set the actual read size, and the marshaller will check it on return and modify the array accordingly. Look at the docs for [`SizeParamIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex?view=net-7.0)